# PassportJS and user creation with postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql, passport.js, pg-promise

I've been trying to use pg-promise with passportjs, but I can't get to work local-signup. My login works well. Please see below:

```
    passport.use(
      "local-signup",
      new LocalStrategy(
        {
          usernameField: "email",
          passwordField: "pass",
          passReqToCallback: true
        },
        (req, email, pass, done) => {
          process.nextTick(function() {
            q.db
              .one("select email from users where email = $1", email)
              .then(data => {
                if (data) {
                  return done(
                    null,
                    false,
                    req.flash("signupMessage", "User already exists")
                  );
                } else {
                  console.log("here!?");
                  q.db
                    .none(
                      "insert into users (email, pass)" +
                        `values (${email}, ${pass})`
                    )
                    .then(data => {
                      console.log("created?");
                    });
                }
              })
              .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
              });
          });
        }
      )
    );
```

The problem here is that, it actually detects if an user is already in the database, but if the user doesn't exists, it doesn't create the username, but instead, skips the whole process.

Any ideas how to fix this issue?

Thank you

Comment: Where does it fails? Is "here!?" message logged? Try to use second argument on `none` method for putting values to query

Comment: Also you concatenate query without any space between

Comment: No, "here" does not logs. It goes directly to the catch method: QueryResultError {
    code: queryResultErrorCode.noData
    message: "No data returned from the query."
    received: 0
    query: "select email from users where email = '78'"
}

Comment: From docs on `one` method: "When 0 or more than 1 rows are returned, the method rejects"

Comment: So try to use `oneOrNone`

Comment: Just tried oneOrNone, but nothing.

Comment: @Blinhawk What do you mean `nothing`? Care to elaborate what is logged when you use method `oneOrNone`? And please update the demo code accordingly. Also, when you are using `q.db.none("insert...`, you are supposed to return its result, because otherwise there is no error handler for it.

Comment: it worked! Just needed to restart the server. Thanks both!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code inside `nextTick` should be something like this:

```
q.db.task(async t => {
    const user = await t.oneOrNone('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = $1', email);
    if (user) {
        return false;
    }
    await t.none('INSERT INTO users(email, pass) VALUES($1, $2)', [email, pass]);
    return true;
})
    .then(created => {
        done(
            null,
            false,
            req.flash('signupMessage', 'Created: ' + created)
        );
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
```